# Why executing PHP mysql_query fails

Tags: php, mysql

Why does this PHP code (mysql_query to delete a row where user name is `$phpVar`) do nothing?

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM xraydeath WHERE user = $user");
```

Comment: And what is `$user` set to and what is the data in the table?

Comment: Sidenote: Always remember that mysql_* functions are [deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use their [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) counterparts

Comment: this form of usage is prone to sql injection. use PDO and bind paramters.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you forgot to quote the `$user` parameter also, please [escape variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) goes into sql query strings. If that parameter is connected directly to user input someone might submit `' or 1=1 --` and your whole table gone. This idea know as [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

*note:* the old mysql_* functions are now deprecated, you should avoid using them, [see the alternatives](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotes around strings like this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM xraydeath WHERE user = '$user'");
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the quotes around the user:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM xraydeath WHERE user = '$user'");
```

Comment: and how do you see that the `user` column is a string type? :)

Comment: I can't see it, but I feel it :)

Comment: @WouterH If `$user` isn't a string,then the query should work fine,right!

Comment: @juergen d Your feelings might hurt you sometime ;)

Comment: @BhuvanRikka: what about the mysql server that is down? a bad connection string? a missing table? a missing column? forgot to put it between `<?php ?>` tags? or no mysql_connect at all?

Comment: Or maybe a disturbance in the force :)

Comment: @WouterH I came to the same conclusion as Juergen due to this line in the question *user name is $phpVar*. Smells of string.

Comment: @WouterH Well,that's the worst case scenario. Depends on the OP's experience ;)

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting? How it fails? Mysql_query is not suppose to do anything in the form that you are using it, except sending the query to the server.

```
 $result = mysql_query (...);
 // use the result if any.
 if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 // check the error that you might have
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `$user` into quotes

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM xraydeath WHERE user = '".$user."';");
```

also DELETE will succeed if even no rows where deleted, so to get how many rows where actually deleted use `mysql_affected_rows()`

```
$x = mysql_query("..");
echo "There were ".mysql_affected_rows()." rows affected";
```

**Try not to use `mysql_*` switch to PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `xraydeath.user` is a character type, the value needs to be enclosed in quotes. If `$user` does not already contain the quotes, try:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM xraydeath WHERE user = '$user'");
```

And for kicks, try setting `$user = "' OR '1'='1";`! (Read up on SQL injection attacks and you should really switch to mysqli!)

---

It's also possible the table does not have a matching row, and therefore nothing will be deleted. Without knowing what you have assigned to `$user` and your data there is no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM xraydeath WHERE user = '".$user."'");
```

or

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM xraydeath WHERE user = '".$user."';");
```

every php variables that used in mysql, put them into '".$variable."'

Answer (score -1):

First : mysql is deprecated. you should use mysqli.
Second : What kind of type is user?
if is int : 
(object oriented style)

```
mysqli::query("DELETE (what you want) FROM xraydeath WHERE `user` = '".$user."'");
```

if is varchar (string) :

```
mysqli::query("DELETE (what you want) FROM xraydeath WHERE `user` LIKE '".$user."'");
```

or
(procedurel syle)

```
mysqli_query((your mysqli link), "DELETE (what you want) FROM xraydeath WHERE `user` LIKE/= '".$user."'");
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You are demonstrating the use of `mysqli` without prepared statements! IMHO this is a bad example of using mysqli, sorry.

Comment: the $user should be verified before executing the statement, mysqli_real_escape_string or something to prevent mysqliInjection.

Comment: No you don't need `mysqli_real_escape_string`, you must use [prepared statements and parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). With prepared statements you never have to care about injections and escaping strings ever again. How cool is that? :)

Comment: Interesting. But still, he asked a solution for executing the query :D

Comment: Everyone is trying to tell the OP to use mysqli, and you are giving a very bad example. Either remove the answer or adopt it and use a prepared statement and bind the $user parameter.